# How do i get another answer?

Tags: python

I have written this program to get the prime factors of a number. I do get the answer but I want to get it in a different way. Now it displays the answer for exemple 100 like this: [2, 2, 5, 5] but i want it like this 100 = 2 * 2 * 5 *5. How do i do that?
this is my code:

```
def priemfactor(n):
    priemfactor_antwoord = []
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            priemfactor_antwoord.append(d)
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
       priemfactor_antwoord.append(n)
    return print(priemfactor_antwoord)
a = int(input("whats the number you want too use?: "))
priemfactor(a)
```

some things are in dutch but i dont think thats a problem

Comment: `return print(' * '.join(priemfactor_antwoord))`

Comment: @MatBBastos You can't join integers, only strings.

Comment: Right, a map would be the case. It seems @Mahrkeenerh already answered with that

Comment: ```'*'.join(str(i) for i in priemfactor_antwoord)```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return the `print()` value, it doesn't do anything in this case.

You probably have a list, like `priemfactor_antwoord = [2, 2, 5, 5]`

So to convert it into `2 * 2 * 5 * 5` you can do this:

```
" * ".join(map(str, priemfactor_antwoord))
```

You need the `map` to first convert each number to a string, and then join them together with the `join`

Comment: thanks, but i'm really new to python so how do i put this in to the code?

Comment: put it inside the `print()` instead of your `priemfactor_antwoord`